# How to setup auto-renewal for "Let's Encrypt" SSL Certificates in CentOS/Fedora?

Tags: apache, ssl, centos, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Let's Encrypt SSL Certificates keep expiring every 90 days and I have been manually renewing certificates for quite some time now!

How to enable auto-renewal of Let's Encrypt Certificates in CentOS/Fedora for multiple websites hosted on Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use CertBot you can turn on auto renewal by creating a cron-job to run the renew command. This is an example of such a cron-job which runs at at noon and midnight every day.

```
0 0,12 * * * python -c 'import random; 
import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)' && ./path/to/certbot-auto renew
```

It runs more often than it needs to just in case something happens to your certificate. And the random minute is chosen to not have everyone ask for new certificates at the same time.

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centos6-apache